# ASP .Net Core Web APIs Dependency Injection Class with Multiple Constructors

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am using Asp .net core 2.2 with built-in DI. I want to inject service that has multiple constructors that fulfill the container conditions. And I can't remove the other constructor for backward compatibility. Example code:

```
public interface IService{
   void DoSomthing();
}

public class Implementation : IService
{
    public Implementation(IService1 service1)
    {

    }

    public Implementation(IService1 service1, IService2 service2)
    {

    }

    public void DoSomthing()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I registered all these services in the DI container example:

```
services.AddScoped<IService, Implementation>();
```

Now I have another class that uses IService as DI:

```
public class ClassA : IService
{
    public ClassA(IService service)
    {

    }
}
```

How Dependency injection container will intialize this class using which constructor?:

```
public Implementation(IService1 service1)
Or
public Implementation(IService1 service1, IService2 service2)
```

and what is the rule for choosing between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only bind `IService1` it will call the constructor that only takes `IService1`.  If you also bind `IService2`, it will call the constructor with `IService2`.  If you have a class (like your `ClassA`) that only has one constructor that only takes an `IService1`, it will call that constructor regardless of whether you've bound an `IService2`.

Comment: I need to bind both.

Comment: Then it will call the constructor that takes both.

Comment: So the rule is to call the constructor with a high number of fulfilled parameters?. thanks.